# Hide - Show or Create Controls in Runtime c++

Tags: c++, runtime, controls

When I make applications (Windows application Form, Visual Studio C++ 2010), i usually put all the controls in the form, which I know it is not very practical. However, I have seen that many programmers don't put more than 3-4 controls in the form, but they add the rest during the runtime.

I could also do the same thing, but what concerns me is that if i add controls in runtime, maybe the user experience lag issues, which is not a very good thing.

So, does a program run faster if you put the controls in the form hidden and show when needed, or the program runs faster if the controls are added in runtime? Which of the 2 ways will increase the size of the application?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no right answer here.

Some forms can be built dynamically so fast the user can't notice anything. Other forms can take much longer. In the latter, building the hidden forms (or frames - part of the form) in the background is beneficial.

Do what's simpler for you to implement and test and see if that's good enough before investing time and adding complexity where it's not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think speed is the reason for hiding or showing controls. I think the main reason why developers hide controls is to prevent users from being distracted or disgusted from the presence of unwanted controls.
Another reason is that some controls can only be effective after a particular condition is being met.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't answer my question: Which is better, putting 13-15 controls in a form and show them when needed, or add them in runtime?

Comment: I think putting all the controls in the form before running is better. You can hide the ones you don't need then show them in runtime when you need them.